# suppress specific part of webpack output

Tags: angular, webpack

When serving a webpack project I would like to suppress a specific output section (see below). How can I suppress only this part?

Thanks!

```
346ms building modules                                                             
6ms sealing 
0ms optimizing 
0ms basic module optimization 
4ms module optimization 
0ms advanced module optimization 
26ms basic chunk optimization       
0ms chunk optimization 
0ms advanced chunk optimization 
19ms module and chunk tree optimization
115ms module reviving
0ms module order optimization 
4ms module id optimization 
3ms chunk reviving 
0ms chunk order optimization 
23ms chunk id optimization
23ms hashing
1ms module assets processing 
12ms chunk assets processing
3ms additional chunk assets processing 
1ms recording 
0ms additional asset processing 
37ms chunk asset optimization
115ms asset optimization
182ms emitting
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a standard webpack output. Do you use some sort of custom webpack configuration/runner?

Comment: its the new angular-cli which uses webpack